# R finding records without duplicates in long form data

Tags: r

Given data stored in long form like so:

```
data <- data.table::data.table(id = c(1,1,2,3,3,4), n = c("1","2","1","1","2","1"), code = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"))

   id n code
1:  1 1  ABC
2:  1 2  ABC
3:  2 1  ABC
4:  3 1  ABC
5:  3 2  DEF
6:  4 1  GHI
```

What is the quickest method by which to find all **id**s where **n = 1** and **code = ABC** but only if that **id does not have additional records**.

In the above data table, the query should only return **id = 2** because this is the only row that meets the above criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are ways to do this :

1.`data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .SD[all(n == 1 & code == 'ABC')], id]
#   id n code
#1:  2 1  ABC
```

2. Base R :

```
subset(data, ave(n == 1 & code == 'ABC', id, FUN = all))
```

3. `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(all(n == 1 & code == 'ABC'))
```

The logic of all three are the same, it selects the `id` rows where all the values have `n == 1 & code == 'ABC'` (meaning there is no other value apart from this). If you are interested only in `id`'s you could extract the unique `id`'s from the above output.

Comment: Where exactly does this exclude `id`s that also have `n==1` and `code == "ABC"` but also have other entries under the same `id`?

Comment: In `all`. If there are any values in an `id` that have `n != 1` Or `code != 'ABC'`, `all` would return `FALSE` and those `id`'s will be excluded.

Comment: I understand, thanks! Looks great! I appreciate the different options.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach your problem, by identifying first the unique ids in your table. Them I would create a logical test like below to filter your data:

```
freq <- table(data$id)

unique_ids <- as.integer(names(freq[freq == 1]))

test <- data$id %in% unique_ids & data$n == 1 & data$code == "ABC"

select_data <- data[test, ]
```

**Resulting this:**

```
   id n code
1:  2 1  ABC
```